Error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/classes/application.properties': Permission denied
I am trying to setup an end to end pipeline with Jenkins for a spring boot application. Everytime I am triggering the pipeline, it's showing me this error. I am unable to find the solutions.
Started by user admin
Obtained demo-app/JenkinsFile from git https://github.com/bandhan-majumder/Jenkins-CI-CD-Project
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mypipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: git
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mypipeline/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/bandhan-majumder/Jenkins-CI-CD-Project # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/bandhan-majumder/Jenkins-CI-CD-Project
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.43.0'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/bandhan-majumder/Jenkins-CI-CD-Project +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b7c6912496ce0690aa2192ff67e0ed89d28f4bcd (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f b7c6912496ce0690aa2192ff67e0ed89d28f4bcd # timeout=10
ERROR: Checkout failed
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f b7c6912496ce0690aa2192ff67e0ed89d28f4bcd" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/classes/application.properties': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/classes/com/bandhan/demo_app/DemoAppApplication.class': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/classes/templates/index.html': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-archiver/pom.properties': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/createdFiles.lst': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile/default-testCompile/createdFiles.lst': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile/default-testCompile/inputFiles.lst': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/spring-boot-web.jar': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/spring-boot-web.jar.original': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.bandhan.demo_app.DemoAppApplicationTests.xml': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/surefire-reports/com.bandhan.demo_app.DemoAppApplicationTests.txt': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/test-classes/com/bandhan/demo_app/DemoAppApplicationTests.class': Permission denied
HEAD is now at b7c6912 Update JenkinsFile

    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2846)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3174)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout b7c6912496ce0690aa2192ff67e0ed89d28f4bcd
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3202)
    at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1355)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-step-api//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f b7c6912496ce0690aa2192ff67e0ed89d28f4bcd" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/classes/application.properties': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/classes/com/bandhan/demo_app/DemoAppApplication.class': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/classes/templates/index.html': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-archiver/pom.properties': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/createdFiles.lst': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile/default-testCompile/createdFiles.lst': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile/default-testCompile/inputFiles.lst': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/spring-boot-web.jar': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/spring-boot-web.jar.original': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.bandhan.demo_app.DemoAppApplicationTests.xml': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/surefire-reports/com.bandhan.demo_app.DemoAppApplicationTests.txt': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'demo-app/target/test-classes/com/bandhan/demo_app/DemoAppApplicationTests.class': Permission denied
HEAD is now at b7c6912 Update JenkinsFile

    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2846)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3174)
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: f8bd5014-d6f4-4ca8-a568-759c806f20f0
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout b7c6912496ce0690aa2192ff67e0ed89d28f4bcd
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3202)
    at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1355)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-step-api//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Finished: FAILURE

Whenever I am creating a new pipeline, first time everything is working, from second time it's showing me this.
I have tried to delete the workspace manually
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/java-maven-pipeline-project/*
Changing the ownership to jenkins user
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/java-maven-pipeline-project
even adding this to my pipeline, but this was always freezing the pipeline, so I immediately removed it
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }

my current pipeline can be seen here
